# How can I parameterize this piece of code?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have got this piece of code, I want to prevent SQL Injection...

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Update Cliente set blacklist='true' WHERE ID ='" + txtid.Text +"'", mConn);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I tried to do this:

```
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Update Cliente set blacklist=@bl WHERE ID ='" + "@id" + "'", mConn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtid.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bl", 1);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

blacklist is bool so 1 = true.
It doesn't give any erros but It's not working, It's supposed to work like this:

I have a form with a field, I put in an ID that exists in the table Cliente, click the button and it will Update the blacklist field to 'true' where the ID is the same as the one I typed in the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
MySqlCommand command = 
  new MySqlCommand("Update Cliente set blacklist=@bl WHERE ID ='" + "@id" + "'", 
                   mConn);
```

to this:

```
MySqlCommand command = 
  new MySqlCommand("Update Cliente set blacklist=@bl WHERE ID =@id", 
                   mConn);
```

You don't need to quote parameters in the SQL code, the whole point using parameters is to let the DB engine take care of data substitution.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter will not work because you are wrapping it with single quotes. Remove the singel quotes around the parameter and it will work. Keep in mind the parameters are identifiers and not string literals.

```
UPDATE Cliente SET blacklist = @bl WHERE ID = @id
```